# what's the difference between /somedir/ and /somedire/* in robots.txt?

Tags: google-search, robots.txt

I want to disallow a specific folder and all of its files and subdirectories but I don't know the difference between `Disallow: /somedir/` and `Disallow: /somedir/*`. which one of these lines should I use?
By the way, what does `Disallow: /somedir?` mean? should I use it too?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: I don't see this as an SEO question. OP has a question about the robots.txt language specification, OP is not asking about how to get more website hits. Perhaps this issue is already decided as off-topic, but given how it is asked I think it should be allowed. I went ahead and answered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to google (https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt),
`Disallow: /somedir/` and `Disallow: /somedir/*` are equivalent, the trailing wildcard is ignored. Use whichever you like better.

The `?` does not have any special meaning in robots.txt like it does in some pattern matching schemes. Therefore, `Disallow: /somedir?` means to disallow that literal path including the question mark.